# table cell font in RTF with lowagie Document

Tags: java, fonts, itext, cell, rtf

I am trying to create `RTF` document with tables with empty cells.

I use the `com.lowagie.text.rtf.*` package in java.

The `font` of the empty cells are all `Times New Roman` size 12.

How can I set the font of the empty cells to a different `Font`?

I have used `RtfCell cellSpacer = new RtfCell(new Phrase("", new RtfFont("Arial", 9, RtfFont.NORMAL)));` but because the string `""` is empty the font doesn't take effect. When the `""` is filled with something except a `space` the font does take effect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to this problem is that the space must be given as a Non Breaking space to the Phrase constructor!

`String nbs = "\u00A0";`

`RtfCell cellSpacer = new RtfCell(new Phrase(nbs, new RtfFont("Arial", 9, RtfFont.NORMAL)));`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is this [validation on line 198 on Phrase.java](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/com/lowagie/text/Phrase.java.html), which is called from the constructor `Phrase(String string, Font font)`. Basically, it checks that the string is not empty, otherwise it won't create a chunk containing the text and font you specify.

It seems that you should either:

1. Pass a space to the constructor:

   new Phrase(" ", new RtfFont("Arial", 9, RtfFont.NORMAL))
2. Create a new custom class (`class AllowsEmptyPhrase extends Phrase`), copy the constructors and remove the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can see in my question I have tried passing a space to the constructor but didn't work. I haven't try to extend the Phrase class, yet.